# Gatling not able to use my Random Data Generator

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I wrote this simple test in Gatling

```
val createUser = http("create user")
  .post("form/submit")
  .body(StringBody(RequestBuilder.createRandomUser())).asJSON
  .check(status.is(200))

setUp(
  scn.inject(
     atOnceUsers(25),
     rampUsers(10) over (5 seconds),
     constantUsersPerSec(30) during(10 minutes)
  )
).protocols(httpConf)
```

I tested the createRandomUser method for more than 10000 calls and it always generated random users.

But this code when Run inside of Gatling, starts complaining duplicate users in just 10 seconds of run

What I suspect is that each user in Gatling calls my random method once, but THEN re-uses the same object.

I did some googling and found [Feeders](http://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder/):

```
val feeder = Iterator.continually(Map("user"  -> 
    (RequestBuilder. createRandomUser(emails))))

val createUser = http("create user")
  .post("form/submit")
  .body(StringBody(feed(feeder))).asJSON
  .check(status.is(200))
```

but this doesn't work.

How can I make sure that everytime a request is made ... my random data method is called.

Comment: If you do a .feed after http object you will realize that there is no method called feed on the http object. the code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here

https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/6p1za3/any_gatling_experts_here/dkm64nc/

```
val feeder = Iterator.continually(Map("user" -> (RequestBuilder.createRandomRequest())))

def createRespondent = http("createuser")
   .post("form/submit")
   .body(StringBody("${user}").asJSON
   .check(status.is(200))

scenario("my load test")
    .feed(feeder)
    .exec(createRespondent)
```

Comment: This solution does not seem to solve the problem for me. Your initial comment still seems correct. Each user calls the feeder just once, and keeps re-using the same document.